# Picking a random number form an Array and returning it's index

Tags: r, probability

I have an array of probabilities

```
A = c(0, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3)
```

The random number formula I'm using is:

```
sample(A, 1, replace=TRUE)
```

It gives me one of the probabilities. What I'm looking for is the index number of the corresponding probability. Since the probabilities could be repeated, how would I get the specific index number that was chosen? Also, it should not be able to choose a 0 probability.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at `?sample` at all?  It takes a parameter called prob which is exactly what you want.

Comment: why not sample the indicies instead?  `a = sample(seq_along(A), 1, prob=A, replace=TRUE)`  Then you can use that to get your value: `A[a]`

Comment: The title and body of this question appear to be asking two very different questions. Some clarification would be useful.

Comment: @ Justin, that would return an index that could have a 0 probability, which shouldn't happen in my case.

Comment: @ Joran, hopefully the edit, clears it up a bit. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a function doing basically this:

```
y <- 0 
while(y == 0) { 
  x <- sample(1:length(A), 1) 
  y <- A[x]
}
print(x)
```

replace = TRUE is redundant in this context since you are are only taking one sample at a time.